# How to use moment.js to cycle through an array

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to use moment.js isSame function to check against an array containing a few dates. Am I forced to use a forEach to loop through all the values in the array or is there a better way to do so?

```js
let dates = ['170521', '260521', '200721', '090821', '041121'];
console.log(moment('170521', 'DDMMYY').isSame(moment(dates, 'DDMMYY')));
console.log(moment('260521', 'DDMMYY').isSame(moment(dates, 'DDMMYY')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _forced_ to use `forEach`? No... it depends on what you're doing with the match - you could use `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `every`, `some`, `filter`... what's your objective?

Comment: Trying to compare the first date to the dates in the array

Comment: Right but **what's the point of the comparison**? What you do with the result will help determine what method you should use to loop. For example, if you only want to know if one date is within the array, you might use `some`. If you want to remove all dates that don't match, you would use `filter`.

Comment: the first date is to check if it matches any of the dates inside then it will do something else. It doesn't change or remove anything in the array. Just to check true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `forEach`. You don't even need to use `moment`. If that's the format of the input data, you're good with simple string comparison.

```
let dates = ['170521', '260521', '200721', '090821', '041121'];

if (dates.includes('170521')) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
dates.forEach(date => {
   if(moment(date).isSame(moment(someConstDate))) {
      // Do something
   }
});
```